# What does the phrase "when the way you get around" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me understand the meaning of the phrase "when the way you get around" in the following text from the description of the game "Bomb Chicken":

> It can double as a barrier to keep enemies away, too. But these aren’t smart bombs – your payload is as deadly to you as anyone else.
> **When the way you get around** is also the biggest danger you face, exploring becomes thrillingly tense and tricky.
> But as long as you’re careful, you’ll never cry fowl – and there’s little more satisfying than mastering the ‘lay and punt’ technique, where you boot a freshly-fabricated bomb down a tunnel to clear it out, or at a distant switch to open a door. [source](https://apps.apple.com/gb/story/a-truly-explosive-platformer/id1502297787)

The lexical meaning of the phrase "get around" is "to succeed in something." However, I am not sure if it fits here.

Answer (score 1):

To get around: to travel from one location to the next.
"The way you get around" = the type of transportation that you use (bus, train, walking, bicycle, etc.)